# ActivityViewController: completionHandler when popup dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller

[image: ActivityViewController]

I want to call completion handler when ActivityViewController dismisses. Here's my implementation:

```
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 0, height: 0)
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [
    UIActivity.ActivityType.postToWeibo,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.print,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.assignToContact,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.saveToCameraRoll,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.addToReadingList,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFlickr,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.postToVimeo,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.postToTencentWeibo,
    UIActivity.ActivityType.postToFacebook
]
activityViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
    completion()
})
```

is it okay?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Quick tip: probably, you can leave out the `UIActivity.ActivityType`; you can probably just say `.postToWeibo, .print,` et cetera (including the dot). Even quicker tip: if you want to delete them all at once: hold the Alt/Option key down and click and drag with the mouse to select them all, but not the things you want to keep. Then you can press Backspace/Delete. (Maybe you knew this trick already)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation (the first thing you should do, really) of `UIActivityViewController` you can see it has a `completionWithItemsHandler` property that does this:

> The completion handler to execute after the activity view controller
> is dismissed.

[Link to reference.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller/1622022-completionwithitemshandler)